# rosmake --pre-clean without svn update

Tags: gazebo, simulator-gazebo, update, svn, rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I was working with "simulator_gazebo" developers version adding some sensors, now that i'm done and want to integrate my package into my repository, it should be easy but it isn't! The problems is when i do a "make clean" or a "rosmake --pre-clean" (fresh make) the package is pre-configured to download the package from his original repository and after that all my work is lost because it overwrite my code with the original version....

Where is the svn configuration of the package or how can I avoid that the package is svn updated doing make clean or rosmake --pre-clean??

I see several files that specify a SVN_URL, SVN_PACKAGE, SVN_PATCH... but i don't know which or how i should modify it.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11365/rosmake---pre-clean-without-svn-update/) by [jrcapriles](https://answers.ros.org/users/269/jrcapriles/) on ROS Answers with karma: 370 on 2011-09-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS gazebo is a [third-party library](http://www.ros.org/wiki/UsingThirdPartyLibraries). The ROS package wraps the standard [gazebo](http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/gazebo.html) implementation.

To modify gazebo, itself, it looks like you need to create a patch for your changes (as a diff against the downloaded version), and add that to the `patches/` subdirectory.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jrcapriles](https://answers.ros.org/users/269/jrcapriles/) on 2011-09-30**:
Ok ok thanks for this advice i will do it! And thanks for your help!

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-09-30**:
You can submit your patch to the ROS gazebo package maintainer. Open an enhancement ticket explaining what it does and add your patch as an attachment. Or, it can be submitted to the upstream gazebo developers.

**Comment by [jrcapriles](https://answers.ros.org/users/269/jrcapriles/) on 2011-09-30**:
Since the package is in its final place, and anyone is going to change the code of simulator gazebo for now, i added a ROS_NOBUILD and now when i do rosmake --pre-clean or make clean the file isn't modified. It's a temporary solution while i discover how to integrate the patches to gazebo itself

**Comment by [jrcapriles](https://answers.ros.org/users/269/jrcapriles/) on 2011-09-30**:
I found one way to do it, i find and replace in all files the original address with the new address then eliminate all autogenerated files (CMakeCache.txt, CMakeFiles/ src_gen/ srv_gen/ src/gazebo/ and the libs that it found conflict with.. then cmake . and finally make. All work fine.

**Comment by [jrcapriles](https://answers.ros.org/users/269/jrcapriles/) on 2011-09-29**:
Thanks Jack, i made the diff patch and added to the patches/subdirectory. Do you know where i have to specify that the patch is needed to be done?